# Moving file selected in listview to another folder with button

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got problem with moving selected file in listview using button to another folder, my code:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Mkzz\Desktop\doki");
        string destinyFodler = @"C:\Users\Mkzz\Desktop\doki\test1\*.tif";
        listView1.Dispose();
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            File.Move(file, destinyFodler);
        }
    }
```

It gives me error „The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.”. Files loaded to listview are .tif ' s images, they are also loaded into picturebox.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: *`they are also loaded into picturebox.`)   If you created images from the files, the files are locked for as long as the images remain undisposed

Comment: Early every line of code in that sample has some problem 

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the PictureBox controls using a clone image e.g.

```
public class ImageHelpers
{
    public static Image LoadImageClone(string Path)
    {
        Bitmap imageClone = null; 
        var imageOriginal = Image.FromFile(Path);

        imageClone = new Bitmap(imageOriginal.Width, imageOriginal.Height); // create clone, initially empty, same size

        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(imageClone))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
            gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;
            gr.DrawImage(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.Width, imageOriginal.Height); //copy original image onto this surface           
        }

        imageOriginal.Dispose();

        return imageClone; 
    }
}
```

Test we can delete the image after assigning the image to a PictureBox

```
private void LoadImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = ImageHelpers.LoadImageClone("Folders.png");
    File.Delete("Folders.png");
}
```

**Note** I'm not the author of this code, picked the code up many years ago.